# Create a loopback interface and make it permanent (FreeBSD)

Tags: freebsd, network-interface, ifconfig

I create a loopback interface using: `#ifconfig lo1 create`

The problem is when I reboot the machine I loose my configuration.

I tried to modify the `/etc/rc.conf` file but I didn't figure the right way to do it.

Can any one tell me how can I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add in your `/etc/rc.conf`:

```
cloned_interfaces="lo1"
ifconfig_lo1="inet a.b.c.d/netmask"
```

where `a.b.c.d` is the ip address.

Comment: thanks it works! (to precise the netmask ifconfig_lo1="inet a.b.c.d/netmask")